# Java command classpath and PHP in Linux

Tags: java, php, linux, batch-file, jar

Hello I have a java jar files and a batch file that I want to run using the java -cp command and from PHP.

My jar files are inside a folder called "jars" in my server and I'm doing as following to run them :

```
//java.php
$result = exec('java -cp "pack1.jar:pack2.jar" pack3.connect.CommandLine -rb batchfile.odlbat');
echo $result;
```

This command is working in PHP when all my jar and batch file are in the same folder as my javacall.php file.

Now I want to copy my jar and batch files to a new folder "parent" so I tried to modify the script to load the jar and batch files from the "parent" folder but I get this error :

```
//java.php
$result = exec('java -cp "parent/pack1.jar:parent/pack2.jar" parent/pack3.connect.CommandLine -rb parent/batchfile.odlbat');
echo $result;
```

Error : Could not find or load main class parent.pack3.connect.CommandLine

Any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the classpath and not the package page path of your main class `CommandLine`

Change this

```
parent/pack3.connect.CommandLine
```

to

```
pack3.connect.CommandLine
```

Comment: I can't change the jar files all I want is to be able to run the PHP script with the jar files on a folder I do not want to put my jar and my PHP script in the same folder

Comment: it is just a matter of paths I think

Comment: are you running form parent directory or directory one level above of parent?

Comment: my PHP script is inside a folder 'I called it php' and my batch and jar files are inside an other folder 'I called it parent'   And yes 1 level above of parent

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for the classpath: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

I think that you must use instead:

```
java -cp "./parent" parent/pack3.connect.CommandLine -rb parent/batchfile.odlbat
```