# Linux Java cp command

Tags: java, linux

I'm on linux centos6 I run this command successfully :

```
java -cp "com.opendoorlogistics.connect.jar:com.opendoorlogistics.studio.jar" com.opendoorlogistics.connect.CommandLine -rb batchfile.odlbat
```

all the jars and the batch file are in the same folder.

If I move the 'com.opendoorlogistics.connect.jar' the 'com.opendoorlogistics.studio.jar' and the 'batchfile.odlbat' to a folder called myfiles what are the paths I need to add to my command to continue running it successfully?

Thanks

Comment: `java -cp "myfiles/com.opendoorlogistics.connect.jar:myfiles/com.opendoorlogistics.studio.jar" com.opendoorlogistics.connect.CommandLine -rb myfiles/batchfile.odlbat`

Comment: What have you tried? Working with paths is a basic skill, not a programming skill. So I assume there is something more to this question than us telling you how to refer to a parent or sub directory?

Comment: Yes you are right seems like I need to rebuilt the jars to fix an issue but your answer confirmed to me that thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java command classpath and PHP in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953552/java-command-classpath-and-php-in-linux)

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.